# How do I use back stack or get getChildFragmentManager() with this specific pager adapter in order to use the back button?

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I'm using Fragments to change scenes in my application, and I've come across the problem where when the phone back button is pressed, the application closes. How would I make it so when the back button is pressed, the previous fragment opens.

I searched for solutions and there are quite a few like using getChildFragmentManager or back stack. I just don't know how to implement it for my specific state pager adapter, of which I followed a youtube video tutorial for.

SectionsStatePagerAdapter.java:

```
public class SectionsStatePagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

    private final ArrayList<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
    private final ArrayList<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

    public SectionsStatePagerAdapter(@NonNull FragmentManager fm, int behavior) {
        super(fm, behavior);
    }

    public SectionsStatePagerAdapter(FragmentManager supportFragmentManager) {
        super(supportFragmentManager);
    }

    public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title){
        mFragmentList.add(fragment);
        mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
    }



    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return mFragmentList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mFragmentList.size();
    }
}
```

MainActivity.java:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements MyRecyclerViewAdapter.ItemClickListener {
    public SectionsStatePagerAdapter mSectionsStatePagerAdapter;
    private ViewPager mViewPager;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        //Fragment Stuff:
        mSectionsStatePagerAdapter = new SectionsStatePagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        mViewPager = findViewById(R.id.container);

        //SetUpPager:
        setupViewPager(mViewPager);

    }


    private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager){
        SectionsStatePagerAdapter adapter = new SectionsStatePagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        adapter.addFragment(new MainPageFragment(),"MainPage"); //0
        adapter.addFragment(new CoffeePageFragment(),"CoffeePage"); //1
        adapter.addFragment(new RegularCoffeeFragment(),"RegularCoffeePage"); //2
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    }


    public void setViewPager(int fragmentNumber){
        mViewPager.setCurrentItem(fragmentNumber);
    }

}
```

CoffeePageFragment.java:

```
public class CoffeePageFragment extends Fragment {

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.content_coffee_page,container,false);
        btnRegularCoffee = view.findViewById(R.id.regular_coffee_button);


        btnRegularCoffee.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                ((MainActivity)getActivity()).setViewPager(2);
            }
        });
        return (view);
    }
}
```

In conclusion, how do I make it so when the device back button is pressed, it will go back to the previous fragment?

Answer (score 0):

In previous versions of the `AppCompatActivity` implementation it was enough to override `onBackPressed()` in your activity, newer versions dictate to implement the `OnBackPressedCallback`, like shown here: https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/activity/OnBackPressedDispatcher.html

```java
public class FormEntryFragment extends Fragment {
     @Override
     public void onAttach(@NonNull Context context) {
         super.onAttach(context);
         OnBackPressedCallback callback = new OnBackPressedCallback(
             true // default to enabled
         ) {
             @Override
             public void handleOnBackPressed() {
                 showAreYouSureDialog();
             }
         };
         requireActivity().getOnBackPressedDispatcher().addCallback(
             this, // LifecycleOwner
             callback);
     }
 }
```

It might still be ok to use `onBackPressed` on the `Activity` level, though.